# Show that the characteristic function of $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\} \}$ has infinitely many discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Show the function
$f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x=1/n \ \textrm{ for }\  n=1,2,...\\
0 & \textrm { otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
has an infinite number of discontinuities.

I'm considering a proof using the intermediate value theorem to prove $f(x)$ is not continuous over the sub intervals $[0,1/n]$ or $[1/n,1/(n+1)]$ which obviously span the original interval and then showing that there are infinitely many intervals $[1/n,1/(n+1)]$ within the original interval. Would this be a legitimate proof?

Comment: Looks good if you managed to prove that... But why $[0,\frac 1 n]$ is any relevant?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please do format your question using mathjax. Check out the link posted by @Shaun. It helps us to read the question clearly and you can also omit any ambiguities that may arise in future posts on this website.

Comment: @Shaun, thanks. First time posting and wasn't sure how to get the right symbols but this helps a lot.

Comment: @sai-kartik, will do. Thanks

Comment: @user12986714, I see what you mean. I was including [0,$\frac 1n$] to talk about the whole original interval but I see now that if there are infinitely many intervals $[\frac 1n$ , 
$\cfrac{1}{n+1}$] within the original interval that satisfy my premise then I've already proved there are infinitely many discontinuities. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proof you are considering would work, but there is a more direct proof using the limit definition of continuity. If $f$ is continuous at $x_0,$ then it should be the case that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0).$ But we can argue that $f$ fails this condition when $x_0=\frac{1}{n}$ for any positive integer $n>1$. Clearly there infinitely many of these points.

For any positive integer $n>1$ there is a neighborhood $U=(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n-1})$ of $\frac{1}{n}$ for which $f(x)=0$ if $x\in U$ and $x\neq \frac{1}{n}.$ Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{n}}f(x)=0 \neq 1=f(\frac{1}{n}).
$$

Comment: Thanks @subrosa, I thought of this approach but obviously not for long enough as I only looked at the fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to  x_0}$ existed, disregarding the rest.